# How to reference text that's in '<slot></slot>' in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to reference text that's in  in Vue.js?

```
Vue.component('component', {
  template: `<button><slot></slot></button>`,
  created: function() {
    // i would like to access the text in slot here
  }
});
```

Comment: try this `this.$slots.default[0].text`

Comment: you could enhance your question by adding the reason for this approach. Maybe there is a better solution than accessing the text. Usually you would add a property to the button and output the data in the button. Without further information we can't tell if this makes more sense or less

Comment: That's right - I can send data as a prop. I just like how it reads in html:
<component>text</component>

Answer (score 17):

*Note: This answer applies to Vue v2 only.*

The content inside the default slot, which is what you are describing, is exposed as `this.$slots.default` in the Vue. So the most naive way to get the text inside your button would be to use `this.$slots.default[0].text`.

```
Vue.component('component', {
  template: `<button><slot></slot></button>`,
  created: function() {
    const buttonText = this.$slots.default[0].text;
  }
});
```

The problem is that there may be more than one node inside the slot, and the nodes may not necessarily be text. Consider this button:

```
<button><i class="fa fa-check"></i> OK</button>
```

In this case, using the first solution will result in `undefined` because the first node in the slot is not a text node.

To fix that we can borrow a function from the Vue documentation for render functions.

> ```
> var getChildrenTextContent = function (children) {
>   return children.map(function (node) {
>     return node.children
>       ? getChildrenTextContent(node.children)
>       : node.text
>   }).join('')
> }
> ```

And write

```
Vue.component("mybutton", {
  template:"<button><slot></slot></button>",
  created(){
    const text = getChildrenTextContent(this.$slots.default); 
    console.log(text)
  }
})
```

Which will return all the text in the slot joined together. Assuming the above example with the icon, it would return, "OK".

Answer (score 9):

### For Vue 3.

The answer from @bert works well on Vue 2, but Vue 3 slots have a more complex structure.

Here is one way to get the slots text contents (from `default` slot) on Vue 3.

```js
const getSlotChildrenText = children => children.map(node => {
  if (!node.children || typeof node.children === 'string') return node.children || ''
  else if (Array.isArray(node.children)) return getSlotChildrenText(node.children)
  else if (node.children.default) return getSlotChildrenText(node.children.default())
}).join('')


const slotTexts = this.$slots.default && getSlotChildrenText(this.$slots.default()) || ''
console.log(slotTexts)
```

Comment: The difference between children (v2 and v3) and text (v2) is that children has all the carriage returns stripped out. It also has an extra space on the front and end of the now single string. I used to use `.text` of vNode for rendering markdown and now I am struggling to find an alternative way. `.children` won't work.

Comment: @Hawkeye64, Your issue may be related to this PR: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/1600. In Vue 3 the whitespaces can not be preserved yet without this PR. But it will finally be merged into the next Vue release! I am facing this issue for my syntax highlighter library as mentioned in the PR.

Comment: Very nice! Looking forward to the merge.

Comment: I tried this code and this didn't work for me. When using slots from the `useSlot` composable, `node.children` was always null. I had to change your `node.children` to `node.el.textContent` to get it to work for me.

Answer (score 8):

### Run the code snippet below that get the slot text passed by parent :

I'm using ["ref"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs) :

```
<span ref="mySlot">

this.$refs.mySlot.innerHTML
```

Careful : `<slot ref="refName"></slot>` don't works because `<slot>` are not render on html.
You have to wrap the `<slot></slot>` with `<div></div>` or `<span></span>`

### The code :

```js
Vue.component('component', {
  template: '<button>' +
              '<span ref="mySlot">' +
              
                  'Text before<br />' +
                  
                  '<slot name="slot1">' +
                      'Text by default' +
                  '</slot>' +
                  
                  '<br />Text after' +
                  
              '</span>' +
          '</button>',
  mounted: function() {
    console.log( this.$refs.mySlot.innerHTML);
  }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component>
    <span slot="slot1">I'm overriding the slot and text appear in this.$refs.mySlot.innerHTML !</span>
  </component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can access the slot text by joining the innerText of all the children inside the slot.

```
getSlotText() {
  return this.$slots.default.map(vnode => (vnode.text || vnode.elm.innerText)).join('');
},
```

Comment: where is `.elm` documented @Vitim.us?

Comment: @P.MyerNore Looking at the code, it seems that is is indeed a public property https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js

Comment: 'vnode.elm' does not exist. Consider using 'vnode.el' is correct.

Comment: I based my answer using this file https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js#L8

Answer (score 4):

My use case was pretty simple, I had a default slot with only text.
Here's how I accessed the text in vue3 with script setup:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, useSlots } from "vue";

const slots = useSlots();

const slotText = computed(() => {
    return slots.default()[0].children; // This is the interesting line
});
</script>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this result will not be reactive if the slot contents change.

Answer (score 0):

This **Vue** composable using *Typescript* returns the reactive text or texts contained in a slot

```js
import { useSlots, ref, type VNode, computed, watch } from 'vue';


/**
 * Get reactive reference to the current textContent of slot.
  @param {string} name the name of the slot
  @param {object} slotProps the slot bindings(props) as an object
  @returns {string} the textContent of the slot
  */
const useSlotText = <T>(name: string, slotProps: T) => {
  const slot = useSlots()[name]
  const text = ref('')

  //get text from every element in the slot recursively
  function getText(nodes?: VNode[]) {
    let text = ""
    nodes?.forEach(node => {
      if (typeof node.children === 'string') {
        text += node.children
        return
      } else if (Array.isArray(node.children) && node.children.length) {
        return getText(node.children as VNode[])
      }
    })
    return text
  }

  if (slot) {
    const nodes = slot(slotProps)
    text.value = getText(nodes)
  }

  //watch for changes and update
  watch(() => useSlots()[name], () => {
    const slot = useSlots()[name]
    if (slot)
      text.value = getText(slot(slotProps))
  })

  return computed(() => text.value)
}
```