# Bind attribute to $slot using Single File Component syntax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to do something very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956086/858275), where I want an attribute to bind to the default slot. However, I want to use **single file component syntax** instead of `Vue.component()`.

In other words, how do I do the equivalent of accessing `this.$slots` ?

```
<template>
  <p-button
    class="p-button-rounded"
    :icon="icon"
    v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>
<script>
import Button from 'primevue/button';
import VueTypes from 'vue-types';

const getChildrenTextContent = (children) => children
  ?.map((node) => (node.children ? getChildrenTextContent(node.children) : node.text))
  .join('')
  .trim(' ');

export default {
  name: 'Button',
  components: { 'p-button': Button },
  // inheritAttrs: false, // TODO: figure out what value this should be
  props: {
    type: VueTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'ghost']).def(
      'primary',
    ),
    icon: VueTypes.oneOfType([String, null]),
  },

  // inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956086/858275
  created() {
    const text = getChildrenTextContent(this.$slots.default); // (Obviously) doesn't work because `this` refers to the current object 
    this.$attrs.label = text;
    console.log(text);
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hack my way through using `$slots` purely in the template.

It's a hack because this implementation always assumes that the `slot` will only be one layer deep.

If someone else knows of a better way, please post the answer, as I'm such a Vue newb. Thank you!

```
<template>
  <p-button
    class="p-button-rounded"
    :icon="icon"
    :label="
      $slots.default &&
      $slots.default
        .map((node) => node.text)
        .join('')
        .trim(' ')
    "
    iconPos="right"
    v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>

<script>
import Button from "primevue/button";
import VueTypes from "vue-types";

export default {
  name: "Button",
  components: { "p-button": Button },
  // inheritAttrs: false, // TODO: figure out what value this should be
  props: {
    type: VueTypes.oneOf(["primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "ghost"]).def(
      "primary"
    ),
    icon: VueTypes.oneOfType([String, null]),
  },
};
</script>
```